# Watchify doesn't emit update event

Tags: javascript, browserify, watchify

I'm trying to build my `bundle.js` automatically with watchify, but unfortunately no update event is ever triggered when I save files.

```
var bundler = watchify(browserify({
    debug: true,
    entries: ['./js/main.js'],
    transform: "babelify",
    cache: {}, packageCache: {}, fullPaths: true
  }))
  .on("update", function () {
    var updateStart = Date.now();
    console.log(updateStart);
    return bundler
      .bundle()
      .pipe(exorcist(path.join(distPath, "bundle.js.map")))
      .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(path.join(distPath, "bundle.js")));
  })
  .bundle()
  .pipe(exorcist(path.join(distPath, "bundle.js.map")))
  .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(path.join(distPath, "bundle.js")));
```

When I use CLI the behavior is similar: Build runs once after start and that's it.

```
watchify ./js/main.js -o js-dist/bundle.js -v
```

I'm using OS X Yosemite.

Answer (score -1):

I am having the same problem. I used the recipes from the gulp repro. The first bundlejs task works as expected. However when I make changed to one of the dependencies nothings happens.

It seems like the update functions is not being ran. However, changes made in main.js files are recompiled. So somehow the task is rerun, but with cached dependencies.